I need to create a Tree chart view in super set, but i'm not understanding the correct way to set the table to the visual work correctly
I need to create a Tree chart view in super set, but i'm not understanding the correct  way to set the table to the visual work correctly
I had create a view in superset to reproduce a metric e had in PBI and the table has the structure of:
with medidas_score as (
    SELECT
        1 AS ID,
        AVG(data_quality_dimension_vl) as score_objeto
    from fact_asset_dimension_data_quality_score 
),
medidas_regra as(
SELECT 
    1 AS ID,
    data_quality_dimension_sk,
    avg(score_objeto) as medida_regra
FROM fact_asset_dimension_data_quality_score as l_check
INNER JOIN medidas_score as m_score
on m_score.ID = l_check.ID
GROUP BY 1,2),
medidas_tabela as(
SELECT 
    1 AS ID,
    data_quality_dimension_sk,
    avg(medida_regra) as medida_tabela
FROM fact_asset_dimension_data_quality_score  l_check
INNER JOIN medidas_regra as m_tabela
on m_tabela.ID = l_check.ID
GROUP BY 1,2),
medidas_origem as(
SELECT 
    asset_sk,
    avg(medida_tabela) as medida_origem
FROM fact_asset_dimension_data_quality_score  l_check
INNER JOIN medidas_regra as m_tabela
on m_tabela.ID = l_check.ID
GROUP BY 1),
TB_FINAL AS (
SELECT 
    tb2.asset_column_nm, 
    tb2.asset_database_nm, 
    tb2.asset_file_table_nm, 
    tb3.data_quality_dimension_nm,
    CASE
        WHEN tb01.asset_sk is not NULL
            then 'ATRIBUTO'
        WHEN tb3.DATA_QUALITY_DIMENSION_SK is not NULL
            then 'TABELA'
        WHEN tb2.asset_file_table_nm is not NULL
            then 'ORIGEM'
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END as medida_dados_atributo,
    avg(tb1.data_quality_dimension_vl) as Medida_Atributo,
    avg(TB04.medida_tabela) as Medida_Tabela,
    avg(TB05.medida_origem) as Medida_Origem
FROM fact_asset_dimension_data_quality_score tb1 
INNER JOIN dim_asset tb2
    ON tb1.asset_sk = tb2.asset_sk
INNER JOIN dim_data_quality_dimension tb3
    ON tb1.data_quality_dimension_sk = tb3.data_quality_dimension_sk
INNER JOIN medidas_tabela as TB04
    on TB04.data_quality_dimension_sk = tb1.data_quality_dimension_sk
INNER JOIN medidas_origem as TB05
on TB05.asset_sk = tb1.asset_sk
group by 
    1,2,3,4,5)
SELECT
    asset_column_nm, 
    asset_database_nm, 
    asset_file_table_nm, 
    data_quality_dimension_nm,
    Medida_Atributo,
    Medida_Tabela,
    Medida_Origem,
    medida_dados_atributo,
    CASE
        WHEN MEDIDAS.medida_dados_atributo = 'ATRIBUTO' THEN MEDIDAS.medida_atributo
        WHEN MEDIDAS.medida_dados_atributo = 'TABELA' THEN MEDIDAS.medida_tabela
        ELSE MEDIDAS.medida_origem
    END AS medida_arvore
FROM TB_FINAL

I need to create a Tree chart view in super set
